# Создание уникального логина и пароля для отдельной страницы Джанго

Tags: python, django

У меня есть две страницы - главная и страница менеджера. При обычной регистрации и авторизации происходит перенаправление на главную страницу, если пароль и логин существует. Мне необходимо создать один логин и пароль, чтобы я могла заходить по нему не на главную страницу, а на страницу менеджера. То есть если `password=='Login'` и `login=='login123'`, то мы переходим не на главную страницу, а на страницу менеджера. Как я могу это реализовать. Ссылки на обычную регистрацию или авторизацию не добавлять!

Comment: А в чем собственно трудность? Разве не логично при авторизации конкретного пользователя сделать редирект на нужную страницу если password=='Login' и login=='login123'?

Comment: Он выдает ошибки как раз на этом моменте password=='Login' и login=='login123', якобы они не праивльно написаны

Comment: Так может покажете в чем ошибка?